# How to move button in Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, button, move

I need to move button in thread, rather I press one button and my button is going right until it reachs end of form. Y is permanent.
That's code what I have now:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thr = new Thread(Go);
        thr.Start();          
    }

    private delegate void moveBd(Button btn);
    void moveButton(Button btn)
    {
        int x = btn.Location.X;
        int y = btn.Location.Y;
        btn.Location = new Point(x + 1, y);
    }

    private void Go()
    {
        Invoke(new moveBd(moveButton), button1);
    }

}
```

When I click button1 moves just on 1  right (per unit right). But I need to it moves non-stop.
Could somebody help me?
Thanx.

Comment: thanx, but it's my university exercise to use thread.

Comment: Perhaps someone should have a word with your professors to suggest that you learn about threading with something other than UI which is not meant to be multi-threaded!

Comment: Ah, yeah David, when I've seen my exercise first time, I've thought: It would be console applicayion, but professor said that my app need graphical interface. So I can't change it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop in the Go() method.

```
private void Go()
{
    while ((button1.Location.X + button1.Size.Width) < this.Size.Width)
    {
        Invoke(new moveBd(moveButton), button1);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but can you sugget me how to call Go method?

Comment: You can use the same _new Thread(Go)_ call you used in your example.

Comment: Generally it's better to use timer as mentioned by David and John, but a your code needs thread, the only addition you need is the loop inside your Go-method and you should be fine.

Comment: Ouhh thanx, sorry, it really works. But what about if I need to call moving method from main method for 3 different buttons? How can I make method to refer my button by parameter? Thanx.

Comment: You could have separate slideButton1, slideButton2, etc. methods that you could call in **new Thread(slideButton1);** instead of Go(). _slideButton1_ method could in turn call **Go(button1)** provided that you add parameter to the Go()-method.

Comment: OK, thanx for you all. Good solution gives BackGround Worker.

Answer (score 3):

### Suggestion

You probably want to use a `Timer` to do this.

Add a `Timer` control to your form, and use the `Timer_Tick` event to move the button to the right.

Use the Timer's `Enabled` property to start and stop the button.

### Answer

If you insist on using a Thread, you want to add a loop inside of your `Go` method:

```
private void Go()
{
    while (btn.Location.X < this.Size.Width - btn.Size.Width)
    {
        Invoke(new moveBd(moveButton), button1);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, but I'm confused cause I dont't know how to call Go method now.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to put a loop in the `Go` method so that it keeps moving the button.

However, using a thread for this is not the best option. You should try to use a `Timer` control instead. That is a better way to execute code at an interval than to have a loop, and it will run the event in the main thread, so that you don't need to use `Invoke` to access the controls.

Comment: Thanx Guffa, but it's required to use thread because it's my university exercise.